# Generate URL link via javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to link to a page that changes their URL daily.
The main URL is https://test.com/ticketform?check=X and where X is the day of the month.
So, for today, July 20th, the link should look like: https://test.com/ticketform?check=20

I currently have this written in my JS section to pull today's day of the month:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getDate(){
    var d =  new Date();
    var dd = d.getDate();



var link = ('https://test.com/ticketform?check=' +dd);
document.getElementById("linkChange").innerHTML = '<a class="training" href="' + link + '"  target="_blank">Click here</a><br>';

}
```

I'm unable to produce any text when I write the following in my HTML:

```
<span id="linkChange"></span>
```

can someone please help?

Comment: `demo` isn't used in the js, you use `linkChange`

Comment: Don't use stack snippets if the code isn't really doing anything.

Comment: yes sorry, I had demo originally. the code is supposed to read linkChange

Comment: Where do you actually call `getDate()`? Your code works fine http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8gyaxjam/

Comment: Where should I add the getDate()? in the HTML or the bottom of the JS?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code using `linkChange` and not `demo`, also call the js function `getDate()` otherwise the html won't be updated.

```js
function getDate(){
    var d =  new Date();
    var dd = d.getDate();

    var link = ('https://test.com/ticketform?check=' +dd);
    document.getElementById("linkChange").innerHTML = '<a class="training" href="' + link + '"  target="_blank">Click here</a><br>';
   
}
getDate();
```

```html
<span id='linkChange'></span>
```

Comment: yes, that was a typo on my behalf, i've fixed the typo in my question

Comment: he also had to call getDate() otherwise nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

You need an element with id linkChange to actually change

```
<span id=linkChange>myLinknotChanged</span>
```

Comment: yes, that was a typo on my behalf, i've fixed the typo in my question

Answer (score -1):

Also, to take element by id, you have to specify proper id:

```
<span id='linkChange'></span>
```

Comment: But i'm looking for the day of the month - not the month #